# Is it possible to set a value on a $watched scope property that doesn't trigger the $watch callback?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to set `count` and not trigger the `$watch` callback?

```
$scope.count=1;
$scope.$watch('count',function(){...});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe the scenario in which you need this? It feels like an anti-pattern. :)

Comment: I am $watching 2 vars. And both can update the other. I'm trying to update the value of one var from inside the other var's $watch callback without causing an infinite loop.

Comment: If the values reach a fixed point and you are hitting the 10 `$digest` loop limit, then consider increasing it and sticking to using `$watchers` to update the value. If you update the value from outside the Angular scope, then your application is going to end up in an inconsistent state. If the values do not converge, then you might be solving a symptom rather than a problem.

Comment: If I were to allow it to run 10 times that would be 9 times too many. If I were to increase that limit, the increase would add to 9 too many. So that's not good. If there was a way to silently update a var (like in Backbone for example) this could be avoided.

Comment: If the variables do not converge, then you probably are not solving the problem in an angular friendly way. You _can_ watch both values together by setting up a `$watch` on their sum (or concatenation) like this: `$watch(function () { return scope.var1 + scope.var2; }, ...)` and then have only one watcher fire.

Comment: They are updating each other sometimes.

Answer (score 9):

You could use setTimeout to wait for Angular's digest cycle to complete and then run your code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.count = 1;
},0)
```

This way the angular code finishes running, checks for changes and then the property is set without getting Angular involved.

Comment: I genuinely did not want this to be the answer. Seems a little hacky. But it worked like a charm. Using `$timeout` did _not_ work probably because angular knew do another `$digest`.

Answer (score 4):

No,   but you can add control variable logic within your callback

```
$scope.$watch('count',function(){
 if ($scope.bypass) return;
 //else ....
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Kind of.  You can use a $watch listener function.  So instead of using:

```
$scope.$watch('count',function(){...});
```

You'd use:

```
scope.$watch(
  function() {
    // return the condition you do want evaluated.  Whenever this return value changes
    // from the previous $digest cycle the change handler function below will be called. 
    // The return value will be passed in as `newValue` (and the previous as `oldValue`)
    // in the change handler.
 },
function(newValue,oldValue){...});
```

Edit:  Since it looks like you're trying to watch 2 different variables, another option may be to use `watchCollection` which will trigger if either changes (so you could have one consolidated handler for both):

```
$scope.$watchCollection(['count','otherCount'], function(newValues, oldValues) { ...});
```

Comment: I didn't know $watch can take 2 functions as arguments.